# Counting commas but not vowels and consonants

Tags: python, count

I have built two functions that use `return` not to count vowels and consonants.

I am now trying to count commas and thought it would be as simple as exchanging `return` not for `return`.

What am I missing here that is causing this to fail?

```
def check_comma(x):
    x = x.lower()

    return x == ','


def countCommas(string):
    count = 0

    for i in range(len(string)):

        if check_comma(string[i]):
            count += 1

    return count
```

I then have an app.py to create an endpoint so that this function can be called by a front end as follows

```
import json
from http import HTTPStatus
from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify
from commas import countCommas


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    user_input = str(request.args.get('text'))
    ans = str(countCommas(user_input))

    payload = {
        'word': user_input,
        'answer': ans
    }

    reply = json.dumps(payload)

    response = Response(response=reply, status=HTTPStatus.OK, mimetype="application/json")
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']='*'

    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=2000)
```

This is set up with docker/kubernetes and the function can be called, but it is returning the answer "0" with any number of commas in the input field

Comment: How about the `.count` method

Answer (score 0):

You wasn't taking the input.**(STRING)**

```py
def check_comma(x):
    x = x.lower()

    return x == ','


def countCommas(string):
    count = 0

    for i in range(len(string)):

        if check_comma(string[i]):
            count += 1

    print("No. of commas are: ",count)
string= input("Enter String: ")
countCommas(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, you don't need to call `.lower()` to check for commas. Secondly, the code seems to work fine for me. I think the problem is caused by the wrong indentation on line 1 (def check_comma(x):). However, you can just simply use `string.count(',')`.

Simple approach:

```
def countCommas(string):
    count = 0

    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] == ',':
            count += 1
    return count

print(countCommas("hi,this,has,4,commas")) # 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need of `x.lower()`. The rest is fine. Here is code you can try:

```
def check_comma(x):
    x = x.lower()
    if x == ',':
         count = count + 1
    return count

def Commas(string):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
         count = count + check_comma(string[i])
    return count
```